# getting value inside array with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, syntax

i have:

```
var myVariable= {
    var_one: ["satu", 'uno'],
    var_two: ["dua", 'dos'],
    var_three: ["tiga", 'tres'],
    var_four: ["empat", 'cuatro'],
    var_five: ["lima", 'cinco'],
    var_six: ["enam", 'seis']
};

for (var component in myVariable) {
    document.getElementById(component[0]).value = '';
}
```

the problem here is:
the component value is actually returning:

> var_one ... var_six

while i'm expecting:

> satu ... enam

how do i do for in loop to get my array value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is iterating over the keys in your object, not the values. So your code would look something like:

```
for (var key in myVariable) {
    var value_you_want = myVariable[key][0];
    document.getElementById(value_you_want).value = '';
}
```

FOLLOW UP:

You may also want to check to make sure the key is a property of the object and not the object's prototype in some cases:

```
for (var key in myVariable) {
    var value_you_want = myVariable[key][0];

    if(myVariable.hasOwnProperty(key)) {                  //Include this condition
        document.getElementById(value_you_want).value = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`component` is the key not the value, please use this:

```
var myVariable= {
    var_one: ["satu", 'uno'],
    var_two: ["dua", 'dos'],
    var_three: ["tiga", 'tres'],
    var_four: ["empat", 'cuatro'],
    var_five: ["lima", 'cinco'],
    var_six: ["enam", 'seis']
};

for (var component in myVariable) {
    document.getElementById(myVariable[component][0]).value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The for...in loop loops trough the indices in the array, not the values.

If you have the array

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

Then a for...in loop will return

```
0, 1, 2
```

You need to use a for...of loop if you have ES6 or you need to do

```
var value = myArray[component]
```

To get the array from the object

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the value of a object key use `object.key`
In your case it will return an array.If you need the element of zero index, do like `myVariable[component][0]`

```
var myVariable= {
    var_one: ["satu", 'uno'],
    var_two: ["dua", 'dos'],
    var_three: ["tiga", 'tres'],
    var_four: ["empat", 'cuatro'],
    var_five: ["lima", 'cinco'],
    var_six: ["enam", 'seis']
};

for (var component in myVariable) {
    document.getElementById(myVariable[component][0]).value="";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the key `component` like this:

```
myVariable[component][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key from the `for...in` loop to get the values:

```
for (var component in myVariable) {
    document.getElementById(myVariable[component][0]).value = '';
}
```

Alternatively, if `myVariable` is iterable, you can use a `for...of` loop:

```
var myVariable= [["satu", 'uno'],
    ["dua", 'dos'],
    ["tiga", 'tres'],
    ["empat", 'cuatro'],
    ["lima", 'cinco'],
    ["enam", 'seis']
    ];

for (var component of myVariable) {
    console.log(component[0]);
}
```

Comment: this solution is interesting, but it giving me error: Uncaught TypeError: myVariable[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

Comment: You're right, it's because the variable in the original question was an object with key-value pairs. I've edited my answer to show how it would work with a `for...of` loop.

Comment: i can't do that, because i need the key value in the future :)